# Declare an array of 20 elements of the same number in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to declare an array of 20 elements of the same number in Matlab by just listing them like so;

```
data = [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ... ] up to 20.
```

Is there a more effective way of doing this to keep my script tidy? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`ones(1,20)*0.5`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html) or [`repmat(0.5,1,20)`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) or [`linspace(0.5,0.5,20)`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) or [`repelem(0.5,20)`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)

Comment: Ah that makes sense @obchardon thanks so much! I am only a beginner of matlab so it good to learn the shortcuts.

Comment: And mostly for fun (a bit overkill): `full(sparse(1,1:20,0.5))` or `~~[1:20]*0.5` or `0.5*[1:20]./[1:20]`. It can be a good exercise to try to understand how those solution work.

Comment: @obchardon I will look at everything you suggested. Thanks so much for you help!